# How to use b:growl

Tags: jsf, bootsfaces

I'm trying to show a specific b:growl element loaded from a bean, basically I'm try to replicate the example from the BootsFaces showcase (https://showcase.bootsfaces.net/forms/Growl.jsf;jsessionid=QdtXGdUxPK9sS714iLGuyksK93AMfZM-WfZm3py_.showcase01).
I used FacesMessages.info, but I get two b:growl messages. So, how can I target the specific b:growl element to show my message?
In the example from showcase: What does the messagesBean.specificInfo method do?

**Edit**:
Thank you Stephan, but is not working for me, I still get two b:grolw messages and the one width globalOnly="true" is ignored and a standar one is showed instead.

Here is my code:
xhtml:

```
<ui:define name="content">

    <div class="container" style="width: auto">
        <h:form id="idForm">
            <b:panel title="#{msg['administrarServicio']}" look="primary"
                id="panel" collapsible="false">

                <b:commandButton id="idBorrar" col-lg="3" col-md="3" colSm="10"
                    col-xs="10" offset-lg="2" offset-md="2" offset-sm="1"
                    offset-xs="1" value="Borrare o o o o" look="danger"
                    iconAwesome="trash" iconAlign="right"
                    action="#{serviceManagementBean.borrar}" />
            </b:panel>

            <b:growl id="growlCommonMsg" placementFrom="bottom"
                show-detail="true" show-summary="true" allowDismiss="true"
                global-only="true" delay="10000" escape="true" />

            <b:growl for="idBorrar" id="growlMsg" globalOnly="true"
                placementFrom="bottom" show-detail="true" show-summary="true"
                allowDismiss="true" delay="10000" escape="true" global-only="false"
                animation-enter="animated bounceInDown"
                animation-exit="animated flipOutX" />
        </h:form>

    </div>
</ui:define>
```

Java:

```
public void borrar() {
        System.out.println("BORRAR " + this.idTramite);
        FacesMessages.info("idForm:idBorrar", "Se boró correctamente el servicio " + this.idTramite, "Nunca va a volver. ¡Nunca!");
}
```

Comment: you should only place one `b:growl` inside an `h:form` or `b:form` element

Comment: I have only one and BootsFacets example have two

Comment: which bootsfaces example?

Comment: @MitchBroadhead I'm almost sure they're talking about https://showcase.bootsfaces.net/forms/Growl.jsf. And it's true, we've forgotten to include the Java code with the example. I've added this to my personal TODO list.

Answer (score 2):

Let's begin with the source code you're missing. [Here you go:](https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFacesWeb/blob/master/src/main/java/net/bootsfaces/demo/MessagesBean.java)

```
public void specificInfo() {
    FacesMessages.info("growlForm:ref", "Info", "This is a specific message!");
}
public void error() {
    FacesMessages.error("Error!", "Something has gone <strong>wrong</strong>.");
}
```

You'll notice the only difference is the number of parameters. `specificInfo()` includes the id `growlForm:ref`. You didn't include it with your code snippet, but `growlForm` is the id of the surrounding form (at least in our showcase). The second part of the id, `ref`, indicates that the FacesMessage is to be displayed by an `<h:message>`, `<b:message>`, `<p:message>`, `<p:growl>` or `<b:growl>` which is defined inside this form and bears the attribute `for="ref"`.

Looking at the two `<b:growl>`s of the showcase, you'll see that the first growl doesn't have a `for` attribute. Instead, it sets `globalOnly="true"`. This causes the growl to ignore every FacesMessage bearing an id. It'll ignore the messages generated by `specificInfo()`.

So that's why there are two `<b:growl>s` in our showcase example, but every user action only triggers one of them.

There's that. Your issue is the other way round: One `<b:growl>` displays two growl elements on the screen. You haven't provided any Java source code (yet?), so I can only guess. The most likely explanation is that you're really generating the `FacesMessage` twice. I recommend setting a breakpoint in your debugger (or adding a System.out.println(), if you prefer that approach) to rule that out.

I hope I've given you enough clues to solve your issue. If not, don't hesitate to reach out to us on our [bug tracker on GitHub](https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues). Please include the link to this StackOverflow question, so I can update this answer if necessary.

Comment: Thank you Stephan, but is not working for me, I still get two b:grolw messages and the one width globalOnly="true" is ignored and a standar one is showed instead.
I add the code in the main post.

Comment: At the moment, I'm abroad, but I'll try to reproduce and solve the bug ASAP.

Comment: @Joaquín I've copied your sourcecode into our showcase, trying to reproduce your issue. But everything works as intended: there's a single growl. I've checked in the sourcecode, so you can checkout our showcase and compare it to your program. The live demo is here: https://staging.bootsfaces.net/Showcase/issues/so20180817.jsf

Comment: BTW, if you continue to struggle with the bug, please let's continue the discussion on our bug tracker (or send me an e-mail). The idea is that StackOverflow is a place where other people running into the same problem find the solution quickly, so let's limit discussions here to the minimum and continue them on another platform.